# Trying to get filestore set up for infinispan

Tags: infinispan

I am using infinispan in a grail project.  I want it to write the contents of the cache to a file when the JVM shuts down and then re-read it when the JVM starts back up.

I try:

```
EmbeddedCacheManager cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager()

ConfigurationBuilder config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
config.eviction().maxEntries(15)
config.eviction.strategy(EvictionStrategy.LIRS)
config.loaders().addFileCacheStore().location("cachetemp.txt")

cacheManager.defineConfiguration("DEFAULT_CACHE_NAME", config.build())
```

but this does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please, specify the "this does not work", and version of Infinispan you're using (there were some changes between 5.x and 6.0).

Comment: @Breako Breako any update on this topic from your side?